# "No such column 'CacheControl' on entity 'StaticResource'" error

Tags: managed-package, standard-objects, static-resources

My problem is that the installation of a managed package I have created fails in one org reporting error codes such as "2143637119-8106 (1481522811)". On repeating the install, the last number stays consistent which I understand means that the error has a consistent signature.

Salesforce support have come back with a stack trace that starts with:

> No such column 'CacheControl' on entity 'StaticResource'

and when I use the Developer Console (logged in as SA) to look at the StaticResource object the CacheControl field is missing. As that field is part of the documented API this is pretty surprising.

Has anyone else seen this problem? I'll persue with Salesforce support too.

Comment: I just tested on two instances (NA3 and NA17) but could not reproduce the issue. I tested by executing the SOQL: `Select CacheControl From StaticResource`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce support say that this error is occurring because the org is a trial org. A trial org does not support sites (which the managed package provides components for) and also apparently the CacheControl field is affected by it being a trial org too.

So the fix is to move the org to full licenses.